# The series $\sum_{k=1}^n ka^k , 0<a<1$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The series $\sum_{k=1}^n ka^k , 0<a<1$ converges?

**My thoughts**

It is sufficient  to show that the sequence $ka^k\to0$ for any $0<a<1$, which I believe is true. But how to show it?

Comment: To show that a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges, it is **not** sufficient to prove $x_k\to0$. Recall that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to show that $ka^{k} \to 0$. Use Ratio Test: $\frac  {(k+1)a^{k+1}} {ka^{k}}   \to a <1$ so the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

The quick way: your series is $a^{-1}$ times the MacLaurin series of the derivative of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, whose series is the geometric series, which certainly converges on $(a,1).$ If you know that the radius of convergence of the derived series is the same as that of the original, you are done.

Comment: Just to poke around, if a series is convergent, are the derivatives and/or anti-derivatives of the series convergent on the same interval?

Comment: If it's a power series, then the derivative(s) yes, except perhaps at the endpoints. And since the partials sum of a power series converge uniformly inside their interval of convergence, say $(a,b)$, then the integrals from $c$ to $d$ where $a<c<d<b$ will converge also.